# Add new row to the view model collection (ASP.NET MVC 5 and EF6)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I would like my Employee edit view looks like the screenshot here:

[image]

It's a simplified version of my page, but basically editing an employee means add a new job position (if any) or change the services to which he is associated.

I want data to be saved in database only when the "Save" button is clicked.

When user click the "Add" button, I want a new item to be added to the underline job positions collection of the view model and then the list should be rendered again.

Only one position can be added at a time, so when a new row is added, the "Add" button (the entire row better) should be hidden and a "Remove" button should be shown next the last added row to let user go back.

I can't find a way to add a new Job position to the `EmployeeJobPositionsList` without saving data to database first.

Can you help me?

This is the (simplified) model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Service> Services { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJobPosition> JobPositions { get; set; }
}
    
public class JobPosition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<EmployeeJobPosition> EmployeeJobPositions { get; set; }
}
    
public class EmployeeJobPosition
{
    [Key,Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("JobPosition")]
    public int JobPositionId { get; set; }
    public virtual JobPosition JobPosition { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
} 
    
public class Service
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
    
public class M2MDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<JobPosition> JobPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EmployeeJobPosition> EmployeesJobPositions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Service> Services { get; set; }
}
```

View models:

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeJobPositionViewModel> EmployeeJobPositionsList { get; set; }
    public int IdNewJobPosition { get; set; }
    public string NewjobStartDate { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> SelectJobPositions { get; set; } = new List<SelectListItem>();
    public ICollection<SelectedService> SelectedServiceList { get; set; }
}

public class SelectedService
{
    public int ServiceId { get; set; } 
    public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeJobPositionViewModel
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int JobPositionId { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public string StartDateToString { get; set; }
    public string EndDateToString { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    
    EmployeeViewModel model = getEmployeeDetailsViewModel(id.Value);
    
    return View(model);
}
    
private EmployeeViewModel getEmployeeDetailsViewModel(int id)
{
    var emp = db.Employees
                .Include(x => x.JobPositions.Select(j => j.JobPosition))
                .Include(s => s.Services)
                .FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);

    db.Database.Log = message => Trace.WriteLine(message);

    EmployeeViewModel model = new EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        Employee = emp,
        EmployeeJobPositionsList = emp.JobPositions.Select(x => new EmployeeJobPositionViewModel()
        {
            EmployeeId = x.EmployeeId,
            JobPositionId = x.JobPositionId,
            JobName = x.JobPosition.Name,
            StartDateToString = x.StartDate.ToShortDateString(),
            EndDateToString = x.EndDate.HasValue ? x.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : ""
        }).ToList(),

        SelectJobPositions = db.JobPositions.Select(j => new SelectListItem() { Text = j.Name, Value = j.Id.ToString() }).ToList(),
        SelectedServiceList = getSelectedServiceList(emp)
    };

    return model;
}

private List<SelectedService> getSelectedServiceList(Employee e)
{
    var servicesInDB = db.Services.ToList();
    var employeeService = new HashSet<int>(e.Services.Select(c => c.Id));
    var list = new List<SelectedService>();

    foreach (var service in servicesInDB)
    {
        list.Add(new SelectedService
        {
            ServiceId = service.Id,
            ServiceName = service.Name,
            IsSelected = employeeService.Contains(service.Id)
        });
    }

    return list;
}
```

I use an EditorTemplate for `SelectedServiceList` and it works well. On postback I can read values for the selected items.

Edit view:

```
@model ManyToMany.Models.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Employee</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <dl class="row">
            <dt class="col-sm-2">Id</dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">@Model.Employee.Id</dd>
            <dt class="col-sm-2">Name</dt>
            <dd class="col-sm-10">@Model.Employee.Name</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>



    <div class="card">

        <div class="card-header bg-info">
            <div class="row">

                <strong>Jobs</strong>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            Job position
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Start date
                        </th>
                        <th>

                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <input type="hidden" id="EmployeeId" name="EmployeeId" value="@Model.Employee.Id" />
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdNewJobPosition, Model.SelectJobPositions, "Select...", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-select" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NewjobStartDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Add", "AddJob", new { EmployeeId = Model.Employee.Id, IdNewJobPosition = Model.IdNewJobPosition, StartDate = Model.NewjobStartDate }, new {@class="btn btn-primary"})
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div>

                @{Html.RenderPartial("_EmployeeJobPositionsList", Model.EmployeeJobPositionsList);
                }

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>





    <div class="mt-3">

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header bg-info">
                <div class="row">

                    <strong>Services</strong>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                @if (!Model.SelectedServiceList.Any())
                {
                    <span class="text-muted">Data not found.</span>
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.SelectedServiceList)
                }
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="mt-3">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-secondary"} )
    </div>
}
```